# "JWT Must be provided " error - When trying to access an endpoint in my deployed server written in Node.js Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, cookies

Libs used in the BE: coockie parser, cors, jwt, bcrypt and express.

I am running into the JWT must be provided error. This happens when I am trying to access some of the endpoints it in the fronted in React and i am making the the fetch call from localhost:300.

I have looked at my backend logic to make sure everything adds up, but i can spot any evident bugs.

any hits or suggestions would be greatly appreciated it:

below is the controllers code and the ensure auth code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Ytb.png)
[image: controllers code]

```
const theTransactions = Router();

theTransactions.post('/makeTransaction', ensureAuth, async (req: Request, 
res:Response, next: NextFunction)=>{
  try {
     const newTransaction = await 
 TransactionServices.createTransaction({sender_id:req.user.id,...req.body});
   
    console.log('BODY',req.body);
    res.send(newTransaction);
 } catch (error) {
    next(error);
 }
 });

 theTransactions.get('/searchrecipient/:email', ensureAuth ,async (req:Request, 
 res:Response, next: NextFunction)=>{
    try {
      const searchedRecipient = await User.findByEmail(req.params.email);

    res.send(searchedRecipient)
} catch (error) {
    next(error);
}
});
```

export default theTransactions

Comment: Pardon me if this is a dumb question, but are you providing a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) with your request?

Comment: @AlexWayne No dumb at all, I believe I am this the middle I have created for it;

`import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

const ensureAuth = (req:Request, res:Response, next: NextFunction)=>{ 
    try {
        const { session } = req.cookies;

        req.user = jwt.verify(session, process.env.APP_SECRET);
        next();

    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}

export default ensureAuth;`